# Need help on understanding of this guide

Tags: java

this guide is given by one of my lecturer and i wanted to implement in java.
But i do not quite understand it though on how to implement in on java. 
Can someone try to explain it further for me? I appreciate a good tutorial though. :)

"Create an array for the text file, look through each text file for the term, once you got the term, you break the inner loop, change the file name and loop again to search for the term. then create a counter to count the number of text file that contain the term. Lastly you will get the number of document containing the term from the counter value."

I has a collection of text files where i need to check whether a specific term is found on the file. If the term is found, i need to increment the fileFound to 1.

Or more specifically inverse document frequency.

What do i need in order to achieve the above ? I mean in code perspective. Sorry, i am slow in codings. No, i do not wish for free codes. I just want to understand what the guide is given. I have asked my lecturer but it does not sufficient though. I just wanted to know how to implement in java. Thanks for your time.

```
System.out.println("Please enter the required word  :");
    Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    String word2 = scan.nextLine();
    String[] array2 = word2.split(" ");

    int numofDoc = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < filename; i++) {

        for (int b = 0; b < array2.length; b++) {

            try {

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                        "C:\\Users\\user\\fypworkspace\\TextRenderer\\abc"
                                + i + ".txt"));

                int matchedWord = 0;

                Scanner s2 = new Scanner(in);

                {
                    while (s2.hasNext()) {
                        if (s2.next().contains(word2))
                            matchedWord++;
                    }

                }
                if (matchedWord > 0)
                    numofDoc++;

                System.out.println("This file contain the term  "
                        + numofDoc);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("File not found.");
            }

        }

    }
```

The output is :

Please enter the required word  :

```
the
File containing the term is 1
File containing the term is 1
File containing the term is 1
File containing the term is 1
File containing the term is 1
File containing the term is 1
File not found
File containing the term is 1
File containing the term is 1
File containing the term is 1
File containing the term is 1
```

i would like the output to printout single output which shows number of File containing the term is 10. It means it already sum up the total. And only print one line out in the output. Any idea sir ?

Comment: What do you have so far? Even pseudo-code will do. And which parts are you having trouble with?

Comment: All the parts of your problem are self explanatory.work on them step by step.

Comment: yes, the text above is nearly pseudocode, just do what he writes there, just in java code ;)

Comment: hi, i have edited my questions to see what i have done so far. I hope someone can point out my mistakes. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just took a quick glance at your code, but it looks as if your variable 'matchedWord' is counting the number of words all ready. You just have to change where you define it and write the appropriate println statement at the end of your method.

Answer (score 0):

Your quote doesn't make much sense.  However the simplest way to find a term in a file is to do

```
if(FileUtils.readFileToString(filename).contains(term)) 
   counter++;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is sufficient information to start your work on this. Your lecturer has given details of each step that you need to do. Just need to write the code for it.

Comment: This will help http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/48905-search-inside-a-text-file/

Answer (score 0):

Only logical answer will be that you have 1 main loop in which you run through the different texts and inside that a loop to run through the words of the text . When the term is found use break; command to stop inner loop and increment the counters. So you need 2 loops , 1 array/arraylist of texts and the counter